# Swift 2.1 how to create predicate

Tags: swift, nspredicate

The compiler is complaining about his piece of code and not sure how to fix:

```
NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment.contains("UITESTING")
```

And it complains that it `cannot convert value of type STring to expected argument type '@noescape((String, String)) throws -> Bool`

I'm using Xcode 7.3.1 with Swift 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment` returns a `[String : String]` dictionary.

To use `contains` on a dictionary you have to pass a closure, not a String.

Examples for Swift 2:

```
// This is just to make the answer easier to read
let env = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment
```

To test if the *keys* contain your String:

```
let result = env.contains { $0.0.containsString("UITESTING") }
```

or to test equality, for example:

```
let result = env.contains { $0.0 == "UITESTING" }
```

To test if the *values* contain your String:

```
let result = env.contains { $0.1.containsString("UITESTING") }
```

or equals:

```
let result = env.contains { $0.1 == "UITESTING" }
```

`$0` is each item in the dictionary, `.0` is the key and `.1` is the value.

To understand better, here's the long form syntax:

```
let result = env.contains { (key, value) in key.containsString("UITESTING") }
```

---

And in Swift 3, in case someone needs it:

```
let env = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
let result = env.contains { $0.key.contains("UITESTING") }
let result = env.contains { $0.value.contains("UITESTING") }
let result = env.contains { (key, value) in key.contains("UITESTING") }
```